# Distribution function of $\sin X$ , where $X$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with a continuous distribution function $F$. Find expression of the distribution of $\sin X$.

The solution to this problem says that

if $-1 \le y \le 1$,

$P(\sin X \le y)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} P((2n+1)\pi - \sin^{-1}y \le X \le (2n+2)\pi + \sin^{-1}y)$.

I'm having trouble coming up with this particular formulation of the distribution. Can anyone provide me with an insight to come up with this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple.  Visualize the graph of the function $y = \sin \theta$.  Now, if you pick a $y = y_0 \in [-1,1]$, that is like drawing a horizontal line at $y = y_0$, and the inequality $\sin \theta \le y_0$ corresponds to choosing those angles $\theta$ for which the points on the curve are at or below this horizontal line.

Now, because the function is periodic with period $2\pi$, it is clear that we ought to restrict our attention to some interval, say $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$, and then any solution for $\theta$ to the inequality $\sin \theta \le y_0$ immediately corresponds to an infinite family of solutions $\{\theta + 2\pi n\}_{n = -\infty}^\infty$.  This why the summation appears in the original claim.

Given the above, it should not be too difficult to do the computation and convince yourself of the claim.